# Getting the title of a UITabBarItem

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

I'd like to get the title of a UITabBarItem created with *initWithTabBarSystemItem:*

```
UITabBarItem *item = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemTopRated tag:1];
```

However, sending title to it, always returns nil.

Is there a way to get the title that is displayed on the UITabBarController?

How does UITabBarController get this title?